FVM install error FormatException: Invalid UTF-8 byte (at offset 5)
I'm trying to download flutter sdk via fvm, but this error is not allowed
C:\>fvm install stable Creating local mirror... Unhandled exception: FormatException: Invalid UTF-8 byte (at offset 5) #0      _Utf8Decoder.convertChunked (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:1851) #1      _Utf8ConversionSink.addSlice (dart:convert/string_conversion.dart:304) #2      _Utf8ConversionSink.add (dart:convert/string_conversion.dart:300) #3      _ConverterStreamEventSink.add (dart:convert/chunked_conversion.dart:69) #4      _SinkTransformerStreamSubscription._handleData          ] #5      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1407) #6      _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1308) #7      _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1217) #8      _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:339) #9      _BufferingStreamSubscription._add (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:271) #10     _SyncStreamControllerDispatch._sendData (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:784) #11     _StreamController._add (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:658) #12     _StreamController.add (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:606) #13     _Socket._onData (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:2447) #14     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1415) #15     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1308) #16     _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1217) #17     _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:339) #18     _BufferingStreamSubscription._add (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:271) #19     _SyncStreamControllerDispatch._sendData (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:784) #20     _StreamController._add (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:658) #21     _StreamController.add (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:606) #22     new _RawSocket.<anonymous closure> (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:1936) #23     _NativeSocket.issueReadEvent.issue (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:1379) #24     _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:40) #25     _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:49) #26     _runPendingImmediateCallback (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:123) #27     _RawReceivePort._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:190)
how can i fix it?
window reset and cmd administrator attempts and also powershell administrator

First of all you need to choco install fvm if you are using Windows.
Then run fmv use stable (or specific version) INSIDE A FLUTTER PROJECT, not in disk C.
